# how I can disable some ngtsc warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig.json

After I upgraded my Angular application to v15, some warnings started showing in terminal and chrome devtool
Is there any way soI can disable those warnings.

```
The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' 
operator.ngtsc(-998107)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it by adding additional config in **tsconfig.json**:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "extendedDiagnostics": {
      "checks": {
        "optionalChainNotNullable": "suppress"
      }
    }
  }
```

Or

You can disable it with installing tsc-silent, a package that overrides **tsconfig.json** and adds additional settings. Do following:

```
1. npm install -g tsc-silent
2. tsc-silent -p tsconfig.json --suppress 8107@src/js/
```

Check the documentation for more information:
https://github.com/evolution-gaming/tsc-silent